# How to make a measurement with a rolling/moving conditional in DAX Excel PowerPivot or Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have this table:

| Period | Firm | Sector | Net Income | Assets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 Dec 2018 | AA | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2018 | BB | 1 | 20 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2018 | CC | 2 | 30 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2018 | DD | 2 | 40 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2019 | AA | 1 | 15 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2019 | BB | 1 | 25 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2019 | CC | 2 | 35 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2019 | DD | 2 | 45 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2020 | AA | 1 | 18 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2020 | BB | 1 | *null* | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2020 | CC | 2 | 38 | 100 |
| 31 Dec 2020 | DD | 2 | 48 | *null* |

I want to create a measurement to calculate the sectoral Return on Assets, i.e. SUM(Net Income)/SUM(Assets) in **year t** , to include only firms which have **a complete set** of Net Income and Assets in **year t** and **year t-1**.

Hence, I want to create a pivot table like this:

| ROA | Sector |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Period** | **1** | **2** |
| 31 Dec 2018 | *null* | *null* |
| 31 Dec 2019 | 20 % | 40% |
| 31 Dec 2020 | 18 % | 38% |

How can I do that in DAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to prepare a table variable containing the previous year set to be used as a filter over the current year calculation.

```
ROA = 
VAR CurrentPeriod =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( T[Period] )
VAR PreviousPeriod =
    DATEADD (
        T[Period],
        -1,
        YEAR
    )
VAR Result =
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK( CurrentPeriod ),
        VAR PreviousYearSet =
            CALCULATETABLE (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    T,
                    T[Sector],
                    T[Firm]
                ),
                NOT ISBLANK ( T[Assets] ),
                NOT ISBLANK ( T[Net Income] ),
                T[Period] = PreviousPeriod
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                DIVIDE (
                    SUM ( T[Net Income] ),
                    SUM ( T[Assets] )
                ),
                NOT ISBLANK ( T[Assets] ),
                NOT ISBLANK ( T[Net Income] ),
                PreviousYearSet
            )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

this measure applied to the sample data can be used in a matrix visual to give the expected result

[image: the resulting matrix]